# When I issue the docker images command there is a "Repository" column -- is this correct?

Tags: docker

I see output that looks like:

REPOSITORY TAG      IMAGE ID   CREATED          SIZE

busybox    latest   1234567..   six weeks ago   1.114 MB

How is busybox the name of repository? Isn't it an image?

I am running on Windows.

EDIT: Is it typical or in fact required that a Repository be dedicated to various tags of a single image? Or can a repo have many different images or is that what a Registry is for: many repos in one registry, one image name per repo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is correct, a repository can contain multiple images, identified by
their *tag* or *digest*.

For example, here's the images that are locally present on my machine for the
`ubuntu` repository;

```
REPOSITORY          TAG                 IMAGE ID            CREATED             SIZE
ubuntu              xenial              537089ecf650        2 weeks ago         119 MB
ubuntu              latest              97434d46f197        2 weeks ago         188 MB
ubuntu              trusty              97434d46f197        2 weeks ago         188 MB
```

You can see that I have three images in the `ubuntu` repo in my local cache;
`ubuntu:xenial`, `ubuntu:trusty` and `ubuntu:latest`. "trusty" and "latest" in this
case are the *same* image, but tagged with different names (their `IMAGE ID` is the same).

On the "tags" tab on Docker Hub, you can see the (tagged) images that are currently present in the repository; https://hub.docker.com/r/library/ubuntu/tags/

Comment: But busybox is an image, isn't it? I would expect to see under REPOSITORY something like ubuntu as you show here, not the name of an image.

Comment: "busybox" is a repository.  "busybox:latest" is an image contained by that repository.  A repository can contain multiple images, often corresponding to different versions of the software.

Comment: Yes, now i see it: When I do a docker run hello-world, it indeed says pulling from library/hello-world. If it had said, pulling from *repository* library/hello-world that would have been clarifying. Thanks.

Comment: If you don't specify a tag, docker defaults to `:latest`, so `docker run hello-world` basically runs `hello-world:latest`. The official images are a bit special, in that they don't have `something/` in front of them, but they're a shortcut for `library/<official-image>`, which can be seen in that output